# Ubuntu thinks that pip3 is both at latest version and is not installed at all: how to solve?

Tags: 16.04, apt, python, pip

I have a strange situation where my Ubuntu 16.04 both insists that `pip3` is installed and that there's no such file as `pip3` (see relevant command and outputs at bottom).

What's even stranger is that `pip3` actually seems to be installed in the *Python 2.7* path:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

**Can you suggest how to debug this situation?**

---

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/openstack/bin:/home/openstack/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ sudo apt install -y python3-pip --upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
openstack@prclnx04:~/python/pybind11$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ pip3 -V
-bash: /home/openstack/.local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
openstack@prclnx04:~/python/pybind11$
```

Comment: Looks like a horrible mess - but I'd start by running `hash -r pip3` so that your bash shell updates its command cache.

Comment: Two different pip3's, and you seem to have them confused. One in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/ (packaged), and another in /usr/local (somewhere else). Maybe more lurking elsewhere.